# rviz crash after latest ros update?

Tags: rviz, ubuntu-lucid, ogre, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ROS diamondback on lucid, after the latest pkg update I cannot start rviz on several machines (all using nvidia grahpics cards). I do get the follwing error:

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
Failed to initialize Ogre: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library Plugin_CgProgramManager.  System Error: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)
[ERROR] [1310418311.062274513]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Could not load dynamic library Plugin_CgProgramManager.  System Error: Plugin_CgProgramManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in DynLib::load at /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-visualization-common-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-visualization-common/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreDynLib.cpp (line 91)
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Thanks in advance

Georg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10566/rviz-crash-after-latest-ros-update?/) by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-13**:
When you say packages do you mean deb packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after trying to install electric today, I found out that I was still using earlier days code.ros.org as deb source and not the packages.ros.org, this obviously lead to incomplete updates and therefore I did not get the rviz updates that solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2011-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0